# gcc - how to force to not add .exe suffix

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

On Windows, I'm using MinGw

```
>gcc --version
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

My link step looks like this: `gcc -o mpy-cross build/py/mpstate.o ...` but the executable produced still has `.exe` suffix.

Is there a way to NOT have it (besides renaming it afterwards)?

Comment: What happens if you try `gcc -o mpy-cross. build/py/mpstate.o ...`?

Comment: @MattGibson it works! and the output file does NOT have the `.` and on windows, I can still call it like a normal `.exe` in cmd.

Comment: Thought it might, though to explain why I think we'd be quite deep into the history of file extensions and odd Windowsy backwards-compatibility with DOS(!) Someone may have a better idea than this kludge, though, I just noticed the question in passing...

Comment: @MattGibson will this affect things if the build is run on Linux?

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect so—unix will probably do exactly what you're telling it to do and create a file called `mpy-cross.`.

Comment: I'm surprised that Windows lets you execute a file that doesn't have a `.exe` suffix (or one of a handful of other suffixes).

Comment: @KeithThompson it does:) I can just call it like so: `mpy-cross` and it runs.

Comment: @KeithThompson, CMD doesn't normally require the extension to be listed in `PATHEXT` in order to find and execute a file when given the full filename; however, it does require "." to be in `PATHEXT` in order to find and run files that have no extension. OTOH, PowerShell and Explorer will run such files only if "." is associated with a filetype such as "exefile" in the registry. You can also execute a PE image explicitly via `CreateProcess`, regardless of the filename.

Comment: Related: https://mingw-users.narkive.com/UtQk79XF/mingw-c-c-re-mingw-gcc-adds-exe-extension-breakage, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66233691/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59471507/11107541