# Remove EXE from Mingw-w64 output | Makefile

Tags: makefile, linker, output, executable, mingw-w64

Preferably when writing makefile, I'd like to utilise as much of the built-ins implicit rules as possible.

```
OUT := afile
OBJS := afile.o bfile.o cfile.o

# detect wsl
    CC := # uses mingw-w64-gcc
    LDFLAGS := # ...
    LDLIBS := # ...
# end of wsl

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
```

The thing with Mingw-w64 is that it outputs `afile.exe` instead of plain `afile`. This is bad because now everytime I run `make`, `afile.exe` is being rebuilt. It would be really nice if Mingw-w64 isn't so stubborn with appending `exe` to my output file.

If I artificially append a custom extension, such as `afile.rubbish`, to the output file, the `exe` is dropped altogether. On the other hand, without any extension, Mingw-w64 forces appending the `exe`.

The implicit rule for linking objects is as follows, quoted from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

```
n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler.
The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

It will also do the right thing if there are multiple object files (presumably
coming from various other source files), one of which has a name matching that of the executable file.
```

Is there a way to change this `exe` appending behaviour to output file with Mingw-w64?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem you have, it does not rebuild the executable each time. The `exe` extension is handled correctly.

Comment: I'm doing this in WSL. So I assume this isn't a problem in Mingw-w64 directly under Windows?

Comment: Yes. It looks like the WSL make doesn't have the special `exe` handling.

Comment: Is there a way around this? In WSL that is.

Comment: I can't say for sure, because I don't use WSL, but probably not.

Comment: possibly related (mingw- not mingw-w64): https://mingw-users.narkive.com/UtQk79XF/mingw-c-c-re-mingw-gcc-adds-exe-extension-breakage