# gcc - suffix suppression during cross-compilation Windows PE on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

System info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 9.3-win32 20200320
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

For a project we are using mingw to cross-compile Windows PE files on Ubuntu. During the cross-compilation we are making modifications to the files. During cross-compilation, the following code is used in the Python script:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc {path} -o {outfile} -static
```

When the process starts we have a file, `somefile` (no extension is used), but after going through the cross-compilation the newly compiled file is called `somefile.exe`.

On an older Ubuntu system, I **believe** it was 17.##, my apologies but the box is offline and I don't remember the exact versioning, we could run the script and the filename would be preserved, no `.exe` appended to the filename.

The addition of `.exe` to the filename is causing some issues with my workflow, and I'm *hoping* there's a way around this outside of cloning the old Ubuntu system to newer hardware. This may work, but logistically it's not ideal.

We're able to make some modifications by bash during the process, but this is creating unwanted artifacts. And we'd like to keep our system processes streamlined.

An older post, [gcc - how to force to not add .exe suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480000/gcc-how-to-force-to-not-add-exe-suffix), suggests adding a `.` to the end of `-o {outfile}`, removing the suffix leaving a `.`. While a great idea, this still has issues with our workflow in that the filename, a SHA256 hash, is used and no extension is looked for (the `.` still causes issues).

If anyone has any insight on how this may be remedied, perhaps modifying the `main.c` file that is referenced during compilation, it's greatly appreciated. I can provide more information if necessary.

Also, my apologies if the post is missing any mission-critical information, I'm new to posting here.

Comment: Re "*An older post [...] suggests adding a `.` to the end of `-o {outfile}`*", That only works on Windows, where `.` denotes no extension.

Comment: At worse you can use `gcc ... -o outfile && mv outfile.exe outfile`

Comment: Instead of the older Ubuntu, you could use the older MinGW-GCC as it seems that its linker did not silently append the ubiquitous extension. Did you read the changelogs or documentation?

Comment: @ikegami - ended up adding the `&& mv {outfile}.exe {outfile}` and it has worked so far in my testing. Now to throw it into the full workflow and see what happens. Fingers crossed!